# Actor in UML (Use case)

Tags: uml

Lets say i have Use Case A (Cancel Consultation),B (Destroy Patient Image) and Actor C (Patient).

Use Case A includes Use Case B, and Actor C triggers Use Case A to happens. My question is, do i need to add a <> from the Actor C to Use Case B ? I was thinking ,Use Case B happens only if Use Case A fires, which means Actor C ONLY triggers Use Case A.

Not so sure that if Use Case A includes Use Case B, and Use Case A triggers by Actor C, therefore Use Case A and B has the primary actor of Actor C ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From description I'd say you don't need a relation between Actor C & Use Case B.

Rationale: A link between an Actor and a Use Case should represent a meaningful unit of value to the Actor.  From your description, "Cancel Consultation" is that meaningful unit of value; it's what the Patient sets out to accomplish.

Destroying the image is a necessary requirement of cancelling the consultation.  However - at least in this example - the Patient doesn't set out just to destroy the image.  Hence no link between Patient & Destroy Image.

Of course: that could change.  As you explore the domain, you might find a scenario in which it's valid for a Patient (or perhaps another Actor) to destroy an image.  Perhaps a Radiographer would destroy an image if it didn't focus correctly (dunno, I'm making this up).

All comes back to the User intent.  You should link Actors with Use Cases that capture their goals, not sub-steps within those goals.

hth.